# I have a 60GB SSD and a 1TB HDD blue, is it possible to automatically designate everything to the TB?

Tags: windows-7, ssd

The 60GB SSD I wanted to be used just for 3/4 games that are used a lot by my family and the OS (Windows 7 Ultimate).

I bought a 1TB drive that's a 7200 RPM Blue edition making it my more or less "main" drive. By that I mean I want everything else on it, all my downloads, most of my installed software, etc.

Is it possible to make it so that everything automatically goes into there? 
Do I have to make folders and manually install everything? Because I don't have an issue to doing it manually, but my family isn't the most computer savvy, so they would fill up the SSD *very* fast.

I don't want to have to make multiple users, and I don't want to have keep running down to help with something, nor do I want to prevent them from doing anything.

Comment: just a side thought, what motherboard do you have? if you have a Z68 motherboard then you can take advantage of SRT (Smart Response Technology) that will give you near-like SSD performance on your 1TB drive by using the SSD drive as a Cache for your Primary Drive. I just set one of these up for my new machine and it is unbelievable awesome. Getting SSD-like performance on a RAID-0 500GBx2 7200RPM platters.

Comment: its a rampage 3 gene motherboard. its not sandy bridge so i'm not sure if it has that feature. but it sounds like a good feature :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use symlinks/junctions to do what you need to do and link the actual directories on the big drive to where they normally are on the boot drive, or to make it easier, you could use [steam-mover](http://www.traynier.com/software/steammover) to to the necessary

Comment: +1: Since they are existing profiles, I'd do the same thing and move the user folder over to the main drive.  Then just prevent users from creating new folders.

Comment: Well it's only one shared user. I just want the user to automaticly create everything on the other drive then comming down and helping my family during installation every time. But if I can shift the entire user over that sounds good.